# didSelectDate func is not getting called in FSCalendar in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, fscalendar

I'm trying to get the date that the user selects via the `didSelectDate` function, but it's not getting called.

Here's my code:

```
func calendar(calendar: FSCalendar!, didSelectDate date: Date!) {
    print ("this func is getting called")
}
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Swift 3**, the method changed a little. Replace

```
func calendar(calendar: FSCalendar!, didSelectDate date: Date!)
```

with

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4**

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition){

     print("date is selected \(self.formatter.string(from: date))"

}
```